# c# Derived Class issue

Tags: c#, .net, class

At the bottom of this message is a class and controller for that class. I have to do this for a couple hundred SQL tables. Yeah.

What I'd like to do is to be able to use a more generic base controller such that a specific controller would be something like:

```
public class IMS_ProductController : IMS_BaseController

    public IEnumerable<IMS_Table> _recordset {get; set;}
    string _tablename = "IMS_Product";
    string _keyname = "ProductID";
}
```

and my base contoller would be like the IMS_ProductController below.

The issue is the first line above. How to I take care of _recordset and more specifically, <IMS_Table> which will be different for each of the SQL tables. You can see in the controller below (which, again, I'd like to turn into a generic controller) that I do things like:

```
var table = new List<IMS_Table>();
or
IMS_Table t = new IMS_Table();
```

Things like that.

Any suggestions would be incredibly helpful.

Thank you!
Chris

```
namespace IMS.Model
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
//using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
[Serializable]
public class MappingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ColumnName = null;
}

public class IMS_Product
{
    [Mapping(ColumnName = "ProductID")]
    [Key]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "PortalID")]
    public int PortalID { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "Smith_ProductID")]
    public int Smith_ProductID { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "IsDigital")]
    public int IsDigital { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "PublisherID")]
    public long PublisherID { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "Released")]
    public DateTime Released { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "Length")]
    public long Length { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "CreatedOn")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "CreatedBy")]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "ModifiedOn")]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "ModifiedBy")]
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "Url")]
    [StringLength(283)]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "dnnFileID")]
    public int dnnFileID { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "dnnFolderID")]
    public int dnnFolderID { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "TypeTagID")]
    public Guid TypeTagID { get; set; }
}

public partial class IMS_Table : IMS_Product { }

public partial class IMS_ProductController
{

    public IEnumerable<IMS_Table> _recordset {get; set;}
    string _tablename = "IMS_Product";
    string _keyname = "ProductID";

    T MapToClass<T>(SqlDataReader reader) where T : class
    {
        T returnedObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        List<PropertyInfo> modelProperties = returnedObject.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(p => p.MetadataToken).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < modelProperties.Count; i++)
            try
            {
                modelProperties[i].SetValue(returnedObject, Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetValue(i), modelProperties[i].PropertyType), null);
            }
            catch { }
        return returnedObject;
    }

    public void gets(string keyval)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * from {0} where {1}='{2}'", _tablename, _keyname, keyval);
        getIt(sql);
     }

    public string gets(string keyval, string where)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * from {0} where {1}='{2}' {3}", _tablename, _keyname, keyval, where);
        try
        {
            getIt(sql);
            return "Sucess: " + sql;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Error: " + sql;
        }

    }

    public void sets(string keyval,string field, string value)
    {
        setIt(keyval, field, value);
    }

    private void getIt(string strSQL)
    {
        var table = new List<IMS_Table>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IMS"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
            {

                IMS_Table t = new IMS_Table();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        t = MapToClass<IMS_Table>(reader);
                        table.Add(t);
                    }
                    _recordset = table;
                    reader.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                }
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void setIt(string keyval, string field, string value)
    {
        var products = new List<IMS_Table>();
        var strSQL = string.Format("update {0} set {1} = '{2}' where {3}='{4}'", _tablename, field, value, _keyname, keyval);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IMS"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Before you continue, do google for "SQL injection".

Comment: You might get somewhere with a `BaseController<T>`  but why not learn to use a tried-and-tested ORM library? Like Entity Framework or nHibernate?

Comment: Firstly,check the comments above.Secondly,have you tried to do that yourself??

Comment: Not horribly worried about sql injection. This is only exposed to a couple of my developers and they have access to the db anyway.

Given that, I'm still going to work a verification piece for the "where" clause. and a couple other things. But this is working now.

Comment: SQL Injection isn't always intentional.

Comment: Yeah...but there is nothing exposed in the implementation of these classes where code can be injected (no forms or accessible input) and the credentials used to access the database are restricted to read only. 

Sheesh. This might be my first .net  project. But sql...almost 30 years now. Databases...over 30 years now. I kinda know about this stuff. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check @Henk Holterman's comments
2. Change your class to `public partial class IMS_ProductController<T> where T :new()`
3. Change `MapToClass` to `T MapToClass(IDataRecord record)`. *Note that `DataReader` implements `IDataRecord`.*
4. Replace **IMS_Table** with **T** everywhere

Comment: Well, no. If the parameter is now an IDataReader probably 
t=MapToClass((IDataReader)reader) or some thing like that.

Comment: DataReader implements IDataRecords,so you don't need a cast.If you want you can change the argument to **SqlDataReader**  to **T MapToClass(SqlDataReader reader)**

Comment: Yup! Got it. Got it working. This just make my life that much easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Final Answer:

```
namespace IMS.Model
 {
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
[Serializable]
public class MappingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ColumnName = null;
}

public partial class IMS_Controller<IMS_WorkingTable> where IMS_WorkingTable : new()
{
    private readonly string tablename;
    private readonly string keyname;

    protected IMS_Controller(string tablename, string keyname)
    {
        this.tablename = tablename;
        this.keyname = keyname;
    }

    public string _tablename { get { return tablename; } }
    public string _keyname { get { return keyname; } }
    public IEnumerable<IMS_WorkingTable> _recordset;

    IMS_WorkingTable MapToClass(IDataRecord record)
    {
        IMS_WorkingTable returnedObject = Activator.CreateInstance<IMS_WorkingTable>();
        List<PropertyInfo> modelProperties = returnedObject.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(p => p.MetadataToken).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < modelProperties.Count; i++)
            try
            {
                modelProperties[i].SetValue(returnedObject, Convert.ChangeType(record.GetValue(i), modelProperties[i].PropertyType), null);
            }
            catch { }
        return returnedObject;
    }

    public void gets(string keyval)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * from {0} where {1}='{2}'", _tablename, _keyname, keyval);
        getIt(sql);
    }

    public string gets(string keyval, string where)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * from {0} where {1}='{2}' {3}", _tablename, _keyname, keyval, where);
        try
        {
            getIt(sql);
            return "Sucess: " + sql;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Error: " + sql;
        }
    }

    public void sets(string keyval, string field, string value)
    {
        setIt(keyval, field, value);
    }

    private void getIt(string strSQL)
    {
        var table = new List<IMS_WorkingTable>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IMS"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
            {
                IMS_WorkingTable t = new IMS_WorkingTable();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        t = MapToClass((IDataRecord)reader);
                        table.Add(t);
                    }
                    _recordset = table;
                    reader.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                }
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void setIt(string keyval, string field, string value)
    {
        var products = new List<IMS_WorkingTable>();
        var strSQL = string.Format("update {0} set {1} = '{2}' where {3}='{4}'", _tablename, field, value, _keyname, keyval);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IMS"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
}


namespace IMS.Model
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public partial class IMM_StoreOrder
{
    [Mapping(ColumnName = "StoreOrderID")]
    [Key]
    public Guid StoreOrderID { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "StoreUserId")]
    public Guid StoreUserId { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "OrderID")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string OrderID { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "OrderDate")]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "Status")]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "DeletedFlag")]
    public bool DeletedFlag { get; set; }

    [Mapping(ColumnName = "IPAddress")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}

public partial class IMS_StoreOrderController : IMS_Controller<IMM_StoreOrder>
{
    public IMS_StoreOrderController() : base("IMM_StoreOrder", "StoreOrderID") { }

}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Generic naming conventions  ,it is better to use a single Capital letter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx#bestpractices_topic2